# Rename spot colors in PDF using PyPDF2

Tags: pdf, pypdf

I need to rename one or more spot color names in PDFs using PyPDF2. I did some search around without any success.
Can someone give some guidance on which approach to use?

With the below, I can read the spot colors name in the PDF

```
import PyPDF2
with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
    for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
    page_reader = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
    colorspaces = page_reader['/Resources']['/ColorSpace']
```

I get the following result:
{'/CS0': IndirectObject(85, 0, 140638024001616), '/CS1': IndirectObject(86, 0, 140638024001616), '/CS2': IndirectObject(87, 0, 140638024001616)}

The description of the spot colors is in the **IndirectObject** .

```
for key, value in colorspaces.items():
    print('Color Space Items:', key, value.idnum, pdf_reader.get_object(value.idnum))
```

Color Space Items: /CS0 85 ['/Separation', '/Spot1', IndirectObject(103, 0, 140514619156560), {'/C0': [100, 0, 0], '/C1': [35.6863, 65, 5], '/Domain': [0, 1], '/FunctionType': 2, '/N': 1, '/Range': [0, 100, -128, 127, -128, 127]}]

Color Space Items: /CS1 86 ['/Separation', '/Spot2', IndirectObject(103, 0, 140514619156560), {'/C0': [100, 0, 0], '/C1': [50, -104, 5], '/Domain': [0, 1], '/FunctionType': 2, '/N': 1, '/Range': [0, 100, -128, 127, -128, 127]}]

Color Space Items: /CS2 87 ['/Separation', '/Spot3', IndirectObject(103, 0, 140514619156560), {'/C0': [100, 0, 0], '/C1': [91, 65, 5], '/Domain': [0, 1], '/FunctionType': 2, '/N': 1, '/Range': [0, 100, -128, 127, -128, 127]}]

The '/Spot1', '/Spot2'... are the spot color names i would need to rename.
Of course, i would need to save a new PDF with the changes.

Can someone guide me how to do that?